# "difference" between two rasters using raster calculator QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, differences

I am struggling to find the right equation to use in the raster calculator to achieve my desired result.

Essentially, I have two rasters, with an overlapping portion. See img below:

[image: map]

I want to only keep the grayscale raster in the areas where the colored raster does not overlap, similar to a vector difference.

I am trying to make a combined DEM for the area, but want to have the colored raster and the "clipped" grayscale raster as separate files.

Can anyone help me with the raster calculator equation I should use to only keep the grayscale raster where the other doesnt overlap?

Or any other method that would work?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do, could you place captures of the two rasters separately?

Comment: @Luis Perez I want to use the rgb raster to cut a hole in the grayscale raster. I want to be left with the grayscale raster everywhere except where the rgb  overlaps.